# $http Auth Headers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I have an angular application that is hitting a node API. Our backend developer has implemented basic auth on the API, and I need to send an auth header in my request.

I've tracked down:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + login + ':' + password);
```

I've tried:

```
.config(['$http', function($http) {
       $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + login + ':' +    password);
}])
```

As well as appending it directly to the request:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: url, headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic auth'}})})
```

But nothing works. How to solve this?

Comment: really strange ... you don't have other things in your config or are you behind a proxy something like that ?

Answer (score 33):

You're mixing the use cases; instantiated services (`$http`) cannot be used in the config phase, while providers won't work in run blocks. From the [module docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies):

> - **Configuration blocks** - […] Only providers and constants can be injected
>     into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>     of services before they have been fully configured.
> - **Run blocks** - […] Only instances and constants can be injected into run
>     blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during
>     application run time.

So use either of the following:

```js
app.run(['$http', function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = /* ... */;
}]);
```

```js
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = /* ... */;
}])
```

Comment: Why cannot we write `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = /* ... */;` in controller level?

Comment: because its a configuration thing, and you're working on one concrete instance of that service.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using `['Authorization']` versus just `.Authorization` ?

Comment: @DannyBullis - just a convention, AFAIK. perhaps that convention was made for convenience; more than often you'll have the HTTP headers as constants somewhere, so addressing the key by using a string allows you to use those constants as key references, e.g.  `$http.defaults.headers.common[HTTP_HEADER_KEY_AUTH]`.

Comment: Thanks @EliranMalka makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Danny You can use dot notation or bracket notation. It's just two different ways to navigate through objects in JS.

Comment: @natureminded thanks, yeah I know that. I was just curious about the stylistic approach. Using square bracket notation allows for using arbitrary property values to define which property you are accessing, whereas dot notation targets only a specific, non-dynamically defined property. This convention is much more widely used in JavaScript than just in this specific instance, but I wasn't sure if there was some other specific reason for using square brackets here. I just needed clarification :) thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @DannyBullis Very wisely written -- just yesterday I hit an issue needing bracket notation so I could generate a dynamic property...well spoken and +1 for the clean description...Thanks for taking the time to write that out :)

Answer (score 14):

I have a service factory that has an angular request interceptor like so:

```
var module =  angular.module('MyAuthServices', ['ngResource']);

module
    .factory('MyAuth', function () {
    return {
        accessTokenId: null
    };
})    
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyAuthRequestInterceptor');
})

.factory('MyAuthRequestInterceptor', [ '$q', '$location', 'MyAuth',
    function ($q, $location, MyAuth) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {


                if (sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {

                    console.log("token["+window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')+"], config.headers: ", config.headers);
                    config.headers.authorization = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
                }
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
            ,
            responseError: function(rejection) {

                console.log("Found responseError: ", rejection);
                if (rejection.status == 401) {

                    console.log("Access denied (error 401), please login again");
                    //$location.nextAfterLogin = $location.path();
                    $location.path('/init/login');
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Then on logging in in my login controller I store the accesstoken using this line:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('currentUserId', $scope.loginResult.user.id);
sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', $scope.loginResult.id);
sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify($scope.loginResult.user));
sessionStorage.setItem('userRoles', JSON.stringify($scope.loginResult.roles));
```

This way I can assign the headers to the request on every request made after I log in.  This is just the way I do it, and is totally up for criticism, but it appears to work very well.

Answer (score 13):

You can use it in the controller:

```
.controller('Controller Name', ['$http', function($http) {
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + login + ':' + password;
}]);
```

Comment: It might work, but It should not be done in a controller

Comment: Should be done in the config phase, but it also needs to be done after a login so it's possible that you could set this in a logincontroller

Comment: Makes perfect sense for my case. 
If you are fetching data from different API's you want to configure it on particular part not for the whole web app. +1

Comment: @LouieAlmeda I think you are right. It shouldn't be done in a controller. But Sjoerd has a point too. You should be able to set it on login. That's why I put this stuff and other $http calls in factories. I think that separates the logic from what should happen in the controller from practical stuff like this.

Comment: @david.carm then set it on your login service, called from a controller. Unless you don't have that service and doing everything in the controller

Answer (score 6):

In the [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you can see some ways to set headers but I think this is what you are searching:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/theUrl',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'token'
         //or
         //'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'token'
    },
    data: someData
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $log.log("OK")
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    if(response.status = 401){ // If you have set 401
        $log.log("ohohoh")
    }
});
```

I'm using this structure in my angularjs client with an ASP.NET 5 server and it works.

Comment: There is no reason to add JQuery to an Angular project just for Ajax auth headers.

Answer (score 4):

In the [$http doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) you can see that you should set the default headers using $httpProvider:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic auth';
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

WORKING EXAMPLE: I have learnt this from @MrZime - Thanks! and Read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers

Latest v1.6.x of NGULARJS as of 2018 MARCH 2nd

```
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.losant.com/applications/43fdsf5dfa5fcfe832ree/data/last-value-query',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'adsadsdsdYXBpVG9rZW4iLCJzrdfiaWF0IjoxNdfsereOiJZ2V0c3RfdLmlvInfdfeweweFQI-dfdffwewdf34ee0',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
                "deviceIds": [
                    "a6fdgdfd5dfqaadsdd5",
                    "azcxd7d0ghghghghd832"
                ],
                "attribute": "humidity"
            }
        }




        $http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $log.log("OK!")
             returnedData = response.data

        }, function errorCallback(response) {

            if (response.status = 401) { // If you have set 401

                $log.log("BAD 401")

            }
            else {

                $log.log("broken at last")

            }
        });
```

Add it to your.js file and include this your.js in your.html file and look at console panel in debug/F12 on chrome you should get OK status and  "returnedData" is what you want in the end. Enjoy the data!

Answer (score 1):

Try base64 encoding your user:password before you append it to "Basic", as in:

```
headers: {
  'Authorization': "Basic " + auth64EncodedUserColonPass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add below line in your `aap.run` method

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';
```