# Basic HTTP Authentication doesn't work in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, http-headers, basic-authentication, http-authentication

My AngularJS driven frontend should use the Basic Auth. I've tried different approaches, but nothing works -- the request is sent without the `Authorization` header:

1. **`$http` service object config**

**code**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('portfolio', []);
    app.controller('ProjectsListController', ['$http', function($http) {
        var projectsList = this;
        projectsList.projectsListData = [];
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic dXNlcjpwd2Q=';
        $http.get(config['api_server_url'] + '/projects').success(function(data) {
            projectsList.projectsListData = data;
        });
    }]);
})();
```

**request headers**

```
OPTIONS /projects HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.bar.tld
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://baz.buz.loc
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://baz.buz.loc/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2
```

2. **request config:**

**code**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('portfolio', []);
    app.controller('ProjectsListController', ['$http', function($http) {
        var projectsList = this;
        projectsList.projectsListData = [];
        $http.get(config['api_server_url'] + '/projects', {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlcjpwd2Q='}
        }).success(function(data) {
            projectsList.projectsListData = data;
        });
    }]);
})();
```

**request headers**

```
OPTIONS /projects HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.bar.tld
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://baz.buz.loc
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://baz.buz.loc/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2
```

3. **`app` config**

**code**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('portfolio', []);
    app.run(['$http', function($http) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic dXNlcjpwd2Q=';
    }]);
    app.controller('ProjectsListController', ['$http', function($http) {
        var projectsList = this;
        projectsList.projectsListData = [];
        $http.get(config['api_server_url'] + '/projects').success(function(data) {
            projectsList.projectsListData = data;
        });
    }]);
})();
```

**request headers**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:foo.bar.tld
Origin:http://baz.buz.loc
Referer:http://baz.buz.loc/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
```

So, the `Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwd2Q=` header is missing. What is wrong here and how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877715/http-auth-headers-in-angularjs) question, you need to set configuration of `$http` service not in controller, but in the `run` or `config` block

```
app.run(['$http', function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = /* ... */;
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've alredy tried this out (see the updated question), it doesn't work.

Comment: then you can look at http intercepors, adding the authorization header there