# What is the main reason to use headers for authentication tokens?

Tags: angularjs, restful-authentication

Just getting up to speed with authentication in angular . What I read a lot is the usage of headers to pass in a token like here: [$http Auth Headers in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877715/http-auth-headers-in-angularjs)
My question is with passing in the token for every request to the backend what are the main reasons to use headers? Is this just for a cleaner solution or is it for performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using headers for this isn't an Angular thing, many APIs use these so that for example a server can determine if the client should be allowed access quickly by examining only the headers and not the request body.  This allows better separation of concerns between authentication and authorization functions, and payload processing on the server.

Upstream servers (of which there may be many layers) can add and remove headers and generally route and authorize your request more efficiently than if this data were to be in the request body.

Headers also keep authentication data out of URL request parameters which looks cleaner but also stops authentication data appearing in browser history etc.

One downside could be that if you are making requests through a network proxy there's a chance that the proxy may strip some headers especially if they're non-standard names.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection to server is HTTPS then HTTP HEADERS are also encrypted. Where as query params are not.