# Add HTTP basic authentication to this HTTP GET in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-get, basic-authentication

I have an existing angularjs code which makes a HTTP GET. Extracted below is some relevant code inside the controller.

```
    .controller('imptViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
        function ($scope, $http, ) {
                    var url = $configuration.webroot + '/impt/list?list=testlist';
                    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                               tableData = response.data;
                               });
        }]);
```

I would like to add HTTP basic authentication to the HTTP GET. The username is `foo` and the password is `bar`. How can this be done?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877715/http-auth-headers-in-angularjs ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because in basic authentication, the username and password are decode by base64. You need to find a library to do this work for comfortable first.

https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64

After that, load `base64` into your app and config headers.

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['base64'])
    .config(function($httpProvider, $base64) {
        var auth = $base64.encode("foo:bar");
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + auth;
    })
```

You can also provide the authentication header to `get` function seprately if you like.

```
var auth = $base64.encode("foo:bar"), 
    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + auth};
$http.get(url, {headers: headers}).then(function (response) {
```

Comment: Your code looks ok but I have trouble getting it working. I have asked another question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429313/what-is-wrong-with-this-http-get-basic-authentication-code

Comment: Your code is working. I think it is my server that is giving the problem. Marked as correct answer.

Comment: Why do you require a library to do base64? why not use btoa() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp ?

Answer (score 16):

Rather than using a library to encode your auth by base 64, you could just use:

`window.btoa("user:pass")`

it's supported by most browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa

Comment: What about post, put, delete, et. al.?

Comment: @DRaehal the way you authenticate a request does not depend on the HTTP verb of the request. If the target endpoint needs Basic authentication, you just apply that header, whether it's a POST, PUT, etc.