# What is wrong with this HTTP-Get Basic authentication code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, restify, basic-authentication

I am using node.js restify as backend to run a REST API server and angularjs as front-end to call the HTTP GET. The REST server uses HTTP Basic Authentication. The username is `foo` and password is `bar`.

I have tested that the backend code works by using a restify client. Here is the working client code;

```
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1'
});

client.basicAuth('foo', 'bar');

client.get('/alert?list=alertList', function(err, req, res, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

I have trouble getting my angularjs http-get code to work. Here is the relevant code;

```
.controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$base64', 
        function ($scope, $http, $cookies, $base64) { 
          var url = '127.0.0.1/alert?list=alertList';
          var auth = $base64.encode('foo:bar');
          $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + auth;
          $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                tableData = response.data;
                //handle data
          });
}
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the angularjs code. I am using restify authorizationParser. Are there any extra header requirements to get HTTP basic authentication working with restify authorizationParser?

The error message on the browser looks like this;

```
{
code: "NotAuthorized",
message: ""
}
```

In the chrome debugger, this is what I see;

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 23 Dec 2015 02:22:04 GMT
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
```

I am using this base64 angular module.
https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64

EDIT: I discovered there is nothing with the angular code. The problem lies with the restify server. The restify server supports static web server and when http basic authentication was enabled, this static web server stopped working.

Comment: What is the error say?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the error. THanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the controller, you can pass the authentication header like this:

```
var url = '127.0.0.1/alert?list=alertList';
var auth = $base64.encode('foo:bar');
var headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + auth};
$http.get(url, {headers: headers}).then(function (response) 
     tableData = response.data;
     //handle data
});
```