# How to do get request from website that is protected?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Site is protected with username and password. How can i do get some data from that page if it is protected. Any suggestion? When i access it i need to enter username and password to get content. I owe that site and i know username and password but it need to be protected because its in develop mode.

Comment: i owe that site but it need to be protected...i know username and password..because its in develop thats why its protected

Comment: Clearly you need to reformulate your question then.

Comment: http://kodex.dev.lapps.ws/ there is a link

Comment: This question has too many issues to be answerable in it's current state.  Not only is it not obvious what method you are trying to use to access the data, it's also not obvious what sort of authentication method the server expects.  Also, "it's in develop mode" doesn't really have anything to do with authentication requirements.  And finally, you have incorrect tags, since [tag:angularjs] **is not the same as** [tag:angular], and code for one will likely not work for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Send an authentication request simulating the login form (using `$http`) to gain an authenticated session, then request the data as normal.

Comment: its not normal login form..  
kodex.dev.lapps.ws this is that site

Comment: You can still use HTTP basic auth with XHR. This should work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413732/add-http-basic-authentication-to-this-http-get-in-angularjs?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Try adding usrename and password in request url like this

```
http://username:password@kodex.dev.lapps.ws/
```

or

you can use basic Authorization header in your http request