# Angular HTTP Request with username and password

Tags: javascript, angularjs, request, httprequest

Im trying to make a http request in Angular, and when i run it I get Unauthorized in the console. But if I run the request directly in the browser (Chrome) it works. Any suggestions how I can correct this?

```
$scope.getStorage = function() {

$http.get('http://username:passsword@example.com/api/storageinfo').success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    }).error(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
};

$scope.getStorage();
```

-

```
GET http://example.com/api/storageinfo/api/storageinfo 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Comment: You could send the basic authentication credentials correcly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877715/http-auth-headers-in-angularjs

Comment: I have tried those exampled, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Please share your back end code so we can understand better.

Comment: I can't. My API is Artifactory from jfrog.