# angularjs 1.6.4 $http post authorization header

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, web-services, api

I have tested the POST in the postman tool, and when adding basic an authentication header, it works with the WordPress API. When I try the POST in angular it is not working. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
var app = angular.module("biodata",['base64']);

app.config(function($httpProvider) {        
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});

app.controller("biodataController",function($scope,$http,$base64)
{
    $scope.datainsert = function(sendata)
    {
        var login = "pms";
        var password = "N^2&DxDLltBTCdKtUy";

        $scope.sendata = {
            "title":"title3",           
            "acf":{
                "firstname":sendata.firstname,
                "lastname":sendata.lastname,
                "dob":sendata.dob,
                "gender":sendata.gender,
                "qualification":sendata.qualification,
                "experience":sendata.experience,
            }
        }

        var token = $base64.encode(login+':'+password);
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + token;
        var test = $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];

        $http({
             method:"POST",
             url:"http://localhost/pms-cms/wp-json/wp/v2/biodata",
             data:$scope.sendata,
             headers:{"Authorization":test}
        }).then(function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877715/http-auth-headers-in-angularjs

Comment: Are there console errors when this is done in Angular?  Also can you post the contents of $scope.senddata?

Comment: $scope.sendata = {
   "title":"title3",   
   "acf":{
    "firstname":sendata.firstname,
    "lastname":sendata.lastname,
    "dob":sendata.dob,
    "gender":sendata.gender,
    "qualification":sendata.qualification,
    "experience":sendata.experience,
   }
  }

Comment: What happens when you console.log(data) in the return?

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: One of the common reasons that it works with Postman and not with AngularJS is a [CORS problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). You should be able to see that error in the developer console.

Comment: Thank you sir, I get error for Unauthorized error (401) and the console.log(data), did not show any console log in the browser

Comment: please see now, I have to change the code, this also have 401 error, what can I do now? please help me..

Comment: @ippi please change my code, and give correct solution