# JWT Authorization

Tags: php, angularjs, jwt

I'm implementing a JWT for secure my API. my front-end is coded with Angular and the back-end with PHP.

I have a problem with the authorization set in the header. I'm sending a request to the server with the JWT that I stored but I don't know really how the back-end read that header

```
users.get = function(project){
var req = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: Global.url_api+'action=GET&table='+project+'_users',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('tokenAPI')
  }
}
console.log(req);
return $http(req);
```

My server isn't able to read that header, the Authorization variable is set to "NULL"

I'm trying to read with :

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);
```

Here is my request in the browser :

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Host: 
Origin: http://evil.com/
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
```

It's looking like there is no authorization set in the header, but my token is generated and stored by the client with the following:

```
if(response.status == 200){ //Status 200 : Everything OK
  var jwt_token = response.data.jwt;
  localStorage.setItem('tokenAPI',jwt_token); //Set the token sent by server in localStorage
  $scope.credentials = true; //Set visible the tab
```

Comment: Please post the content of your request as text, not as image.

Comment: Try to check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877715/http-auth-headers-in-angularjs

Comment: `Origin: http://evil.com/` ?

Comment: Yes ? What is this ? i did nothing for that